# Python Selenium: wait until an element is no longer stale?

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, automation, python-unittest

I have a situation in which I want to wait until an element is no longer STALE i.e. until an elements gets connected to the DOM. Following wait options do not work somehow:

```
self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "elementID")))
self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "elementID")))
```

Its opposite wait function is present which waits until an element becomes stale, which is:

```
self.wait.until(EC.staleness_of((By.ID, "elementID")))
```

But I want it to wait until the element is NO LONGER STALE i.e. until it gets connected to the DOM. How can I achieve this functionality?

EDIT: there is a solution here : [here](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2012/06/staleelementexception.html) but I am looking for any other better approach if any.

Comment: What is your next action/step once the element is `no longer STALE`?

Comment: I'm confused. "Stale" means to me that the element was present before but now is gone. So, "no longer stale" does not make any sense to me?! I think it should work following the proposed answers (using `presence_of_element_located`). If it doesn't, something else is going wrong. Is the site using java or anything else that could dynamically change it? For testing purposes: Does it work if you build in a static extremely long wait (let's say, 120 seconds)?

Comment: @nostradamus by "no longer Stale" I mean that the element is connected to the DOM now.  and yes I have used time.sleep() that makes the code work, but i want to implement it without using time.sleep() function.

Comment: I want my system to wait for an element to get attached to the DOM more precisely @DebanjanB . After that I want to pick its text property.

Comment: You have to identify the piece of code that is changing / updating your element, which then leads to its staleness. It's most likely specific to the page you are looking at, so we can not help you with that. What about a dirty solution: `try ... except`, catch error if element is stale, wait 1 second, repeat this until successful?

Comment: @nostradamus yes at this moment I am using the exact same solution which you are describing, try catch and retry, but I was looking for a better solution if any. thanks

Answer (score 12):

A stale element is an element reference that you have stored that is no longer valid because the page, part of the page, or maybe just the element was refreshed. A simple example

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("elementID")
# do something that refreshes the page
element.click()
```

Here `element.click()` will throw a stale element exception because the reference was stored *before* the refresh but used (clicked) *after* the refresh. In this case, that reference is no longer valid. Once a reference is stale, it never becomes "unstale"... that reference can never be used again. The only way to fix that is to store the reference again.

NOTE: Your code sample is not correct for `.staleness_of()`. It takes a web element reference, not a locator. You need an existing reference to wait for it to go stale. See [the docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.staleness_of).

Now to solve the problem... you need to wait for the refresh to complete and *then get a new reference*.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("elementID")
# do something that refreshes the element
self.wait.until(EC.staleness_of(element))
element = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "elementID")))
# do something with element
```

Waiting for the element to become stale waits for the element reference to be lost, which means the element has changed/refreshed. Once we know the element has changed, we can now get a new reference to it. In this case, waiting for the element to become visible. We now have a new reference stored in our variable that we can use without stale element exceptions.

Comment: This was the less ugly solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#staleness_of):

**Staleness of**:

```
class staleness_of(object):
    """ Wait until an element is no longer attached to the DOM.
    element is the element to wait for.
    returns False if the element is still attached to the DOM, true otherwise.
    """
    def __init__(self, element):
        self.element = element

    def __call__(self, ignored):
        try:
            # Calling any method forces a staleness check
            self.element.is_enabled()
            return False
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return True
```

**Element to be clickable**:

```
class element_to_be_clickable(object):
    """ An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that
    you can click it."""
    def __init__(self, locator):
        self.locator = locator

    def __call__(self, driver):
        element = visibility_of_element_located(self.locator)(driver)
        if element and element.is_enabled():
            return element
        else:
            return False
```

As you can see, both use the same method **is_enabled()** in order to perform the check.

Comment: I have tried this function but it raises StaleElementException.

Answer (score -2):

```
WebDriverWait(browser, waitTime).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH or By.id or w/e you want, " xpath or id name")))
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question, this function does not help and still it raises StaleElementException.