# selenium - waiting for item to load (stale element reference error)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am executing a script which clicks through a number of pages to retrieve data. After each click the new page obviously has to load and the time to load varies greatly (mostly 2-3 seconds, sometimes > 20 seconds). Thus, I need to make the code flexible to wait with executing until the element is loaded. I have implemented the solution below, but I still get a stale element reference error, which I do not understand (as the code should not exit the while loop before the loading is completed). Can anyone explain why this happens/ what I can do to resolve?

Sorry in advance, I am not able to share an executable script with you.

```
error = 1 
if page_ref < Max_pagenum_1: 
    while error == 1: 
        try: 
            link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(@class,"page-item") and contains(@class,"active")]/following-sibling::li/a').click()
            error = 0
            time.sleep(3)
        except: 
            error = 1
            time.sleep(20)
        else: 
            print('finished' + Name)
```

Comment: Update the question with your relevant _HTML_, _code trials_ and _error stack trace_ (if any)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968770/python-selenium-wait-until-an-element-is-no-longer-stale/52836429#52836429)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wait statements. Something along the lines of:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

error = 1 
if page_ref < Max_pagenum_1: 
    while error == 1: 
        try:
            WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//li[contains(@class,"page-item") and contains(@class,"active")]/following-sibling::li/a')))

            link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(@class,"page-item") and contains(@class,"active")]/following-sibling::li/a').click()
            error = 0
            time.sleep(3)
        except: 
            error = 1
            time.sleep(20)
        else: 
            print('finished' + Name)
```

Comment: Works! Thanks for you help @Lafa