# Using Python Selenium getting "selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException" error

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get all the values of one dropdown field and then looping over those values. While looping, I am trying to select each dropdown value. Now, with each selection, another dropdown field gets populated. So, it's a dependent dropdown field.

So far I able to get all the dropdown values and I am able to loop over those values. But the main problem facing is when I select each value. When I select each value, it sends a post request, refreshes the whole page and fills the dependent dropdown with the values.

Now, I am using this below python script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import stalenessOf

import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_script_timeout(10)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://test.aspx")

district_list = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("DistrictList"))

for district in district_list.options:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'DistrictList')))
    district_name = district.get_attribute("text")
    print("District is: %s" % district_name)
    district_list.select_by_visible_text(district_name)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'DistrictList')))
```

but I am getting this error

**selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of  is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed**

**EDIT:** *Complete error response:*

```
(base) F:\Projects\GitHub\Capture_Ocr>python selenium_dropdown.py
District is: -- Select District --
District is: Ahmednagar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selenium_dropdown.py", line 20, in <module>
    district_name = district.get_attribute("text")
  File "C:\Users\Kapil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 141, in get_attribute
    self, name)
  File "C:\Users\Kapil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Kapil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Kapil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <option> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

Now, I have gone through some links here on StackOverflow, such as

[Python Selenium: wait until an element is no longer stale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968770/python-selenium-wait-until-an-element-is-no-longer-stale)

and others but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cory Goldberg explained the root cause for the stale element exception. Here is the solution to handle the issue.

```
# get number of options in the district list
distrOptions= len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@name='DistrictList']/option")))

# loop through all the options using the option index
for distNum in range(distrOptions):
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'DistrictList')))
    # get the district element based on index
    districtEle = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//select[@name='DistrictList']/option)[" + str(distNum+1) +"]"))
    # get district name
    district_name = districtEle.get_attribute("text")
    # print the district Name
    print("District is: %s" % district_name)
    # select district from the list box
    districtEle.click()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'DistrictList')))
```

Answer (score 0):

> it sends a post request, refreshes the 
>   whole page and fills the dependent 
>   dropdown with the values.

explanation:

when the new page is loaded, you lose all references to elements on the previous page... So, the 2nd time through your loop, you are trying to access an element on the *original* page, which no longer exists... so you get a `StaleElementReferenceException`.

Basically, you can't do anything that triggers navigation while iterating over elements, or you will get this.  You need to fetch new elements each time the page reloads.

Comment: ok, so that means, in my scenario, in each loop I'll have to get the content of the page in selenium driver and then proceed. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It will be really complicated because I have 3 more dropdowns which are dependent on each other and later one captch field needs to fill. Once I go through this then I'll have to download multiple pdf files. I think I have to check some other ways to do it.

Comment: to clarify, you don't need to fetch the page again, but you do need to re-find elements.